# How to convert value to type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following enum defined:

```
enum FilterType {
  Number = 'number',
  Text = 'text',
  Other = 'other',
}
```

Then later on I have:

```
switch(filterType) {
case FilterType.Number;
  return createFilter(name, filter as Filter<FilterType.Number>);
case FilterType.Text;
  return createFilter(name, filter as Filter<FilterType.Text>);
case FilterType.Other;
  return createFilter(name, filter as Filter<FilterType.Other>);
}
```

I wonder if I can simplify this code block as it is exactly the same except casting filter to different types.

I tried this but apparently it doesn't work as you cannot put value in place of a type.

```
return createFilter(name, filter as Filter<filterType>);
```

Comment: how `Filter` is defined?

Comment: is `return createFilter(name, filter as Filter<typeof filterType>)` working for you?